# Error: "Bad state: No element" when using BLoC_pattern

Tags: flutter, state, bloc

I need help.
I try to show a list of people in ListView.builder.

This is my code :

```
class TripMembersList extends StatelessWidget {
  const TripMembersList({
    Key? key,
    required this.tripMembers,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final List<User> tripMembers;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 20,
        ),
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          print('tripMembers.length');
          print('tripMembers.length');
          print(tripMembers.length);
          return TripMemberCard(
            tripMember: tripMembers[index],
          );
        },
        itemCount: tripMembers.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

print - 2
I/flutter (13407): tripMembers.length
I/flutter (13407): 2

But I keep getting an error :
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Bad state: No element
The relevant error-causing widget was
BlocBuilder<GradesBloc, GradesState>

And my screen looks like this :

[image]

```
class TripMemberCard extends StatelessWidget {
const TripMemberCard({
Key? key,
required this.tripMember,
}) : super(key: key);
 final User tripMember;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      showDialog<dynamic>(
        context: context,
        useRootNavigator: false,
        builder: (context) => ChatProfileDialog(
          user: tripMember,
        ),
      );
    },
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            MemberWidget(user: tripMember),
          ],
        ),
        const Divider(
          height: 10,
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 214, 211, 211),
          thickness: 1,
        ),
      ],
    ),
   ),
   );
   }
  }



 class MemberWidget extends StatelessWidget {
 const MemberWidget({
 Key? key,
 required this.user,
 }) : super(key: key);

 final User user;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final screenHeigh = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  final isSmallScreen = screenHeigh < 700;

   return BlocBuilder<GradesBloc, GradesState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        showUser(
          context: context,
          user: user,
        );
      },
      child: SizedBox(
        height: isSmallScreen ? 50 : 70,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Hero(
              tag: 'avatar-${user.id}',
              child: AvatarImg(
                dimension: screenHeigh / 20,
                pictureUrl: user.picture,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 10, height: 10),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        user.name,
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .headlineSmall
                            ?.copyWith(
                              fontSize: isSmallScreen ?15:20,
                            ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 3),
                      Center(
                        child: Text(
                          '${user.userMark() ?? '0'} ⭐',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .bodySmall
                              ?.copyWith(
                                fontSize:isSmallScreen ? 12:15,
                              ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 40,
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (state.participantState) {
                            addParticipantGrade(
                              context: context,
                              tripMember: user,
                            );
                          } else {
                            addOrganizerGrade(
                              context: context,
                              tripMember: user,
                            );
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Leave a rating',
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .headlineSmall
                              ?.copyWith(
                                fontSize: isSmallScreen ?15:20,
                                color: AppColor.blue,
                              ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              ),
          ],
           ),
          ),
         );
      },
    );
   }
   }
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Please post the entire stack and also your complete code. The error references a `BlocBuilder`  which isn't visible in your snippet.

Comment: You're right. I've already corrected it.